# How to confine geometry nodes output to a space?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have used geometry nodes to grow trees, bushes and plants, which generally works like a charm. However, sometimes I would like to have a little more control over the output, like when growing an hedge, or a neatly clipped buxus tree, preferably through a cage-like construct. Does anyone have a general idea on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Hmm.. you could clip(limit), cut, or prevent growth. I'm sure there are other ways, too... it depends on what the look/existing method will take. Can you give an  example of what workflow you want to extend?

Comment: It boils down to instancing curves on curves on curves etc, to create a tree-like structure, with leaves/flowers/berries on the highest level. In theory, you can stop instantiating when you are too close to the sides of a cage, but this will also prune branches that are about to grow back into the cage.